# First of type for multiple elements selection

Tags: jquery, html, css, selector, multiple-entries

On the page I am working on the breadcrumbs at the top are shifted on some pages and fine on the others. I used a jquery command that set the offset of the breadcrumbs equal to the offset of the **h1** element. This lines up the breadcrumbs with the header and the rest of the page. However some pages of **h2** or **h3** for the title. How can I select the first header element regardless of the number?

I'm trying to find something like: **h1,h2,h3:first-of-type** that would select the first occurrence of any 1 of these elements not all of them.

Comment: can you post the HTML?.so it will be easy to clear...

Comment: Its already been solved but heres what I meant: http://jsfiddle.net/MkjXc/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use filter:

```
$('h1,h2,h3').filter(':first')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m37q7/)

Comment: That did exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.